# Use AWK to look-up 3 values from 1 file using 3 values from a second file

Tags: awk

I have two files. (the two real files would be 50-100 lines long).

File 1 has records consisting of 4 fields.
Name; Raw Reading Score; Raw Math Score; Raw Science Score

File 2 has records (a look-up table) consisting of 4 fields
Raw Score; Converted Reading; Converted Math; Converted Science
This file might contain duplicate entries for any given conversion of raw score
e.g., raw score 8 and 9 both equal converted score of 50 for Science.

I'd like to create an output file consisting of 7 fields:
Name; Raw Reading Score; Converted Reading; Raw Math Score; Converted Math; Raw Science Score; Converted Science

So for Smith in my example below, the results of the scores 
3,7,4 should be:
3-5, 7-5, 4-15 (I've added spaced, dashes and commas for readabilty)

Sample File 1 (name and 3 raw scores)

```
Smith;3;7;4
Jones;8;2;9
Doe;1;9;4
```

Sample File 2 (raw and 3 converted scores)

```
1;1;1;1
2;3;2;5
3;5;2;10
4;6;3;15
5;8;4;22
6;11;5;35
7;15;5;43
8;18;6;50
9;20;7;50
```

Desired Output File (Name, then alternating 3 raw and 3 converted scores)

```
Smith;3;5;7;5;4;15
Jones;8;18;2;2;9;50
Doe;1;1;9;7;4;15
```

So I think I'd like to read file 2 into an array and then read in file 1, using the array to look-up the converted scores and then output name and 3 sets of raw and converted scores.

Is this a do-able task for AWK, or should I look elsewhere?

Thanks,

Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=";" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}
{
split(a[$2],b)
split(a[$3],c)
split(a[$4],d)
print $1,$2,b[2],$3,c[3],$4,d[4]}' file2 file1
```

Comment: I didn't understand the -v on the first line.  I tweaked it a bit and it works OK. I'll have to read up on the split command.  Thanks.

Comment: @user2574126 it is same as others' `BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=";"}NR==FNR{s[$1,1]=$2;s[$1,2]=$3;s[$1,3]=$4;next}{print $1,$2,s[$2,1],$3,s[$3,2],$4,s[$4,3]}' table people
```

Note the reversal of files.

An explanation:

```
# Before processing any lines
BEGIN{ 
    # Set the input and output field separators
    OFS=FS=";"
}
# For the first file
NR==FNR { 
    # Record the mappings - $1 is the first field, $2 the second, etc.
    s[$1,1]=$2;
    s[$1,2]=$3;
    s[$1,3]=$4;
    # Skip to the next line. This is often used 
    # instead of putting the opposite condition 
    # on the rest of the blocks, or putting a big 
    # if/else in one block.
    next
}
# Every line that reaches here, i.e. the second file
{
    # Print the student's name followed by each score raw and mapped.
    print $1, $2, s[$2,1], $3, s[$3,2], $4, s[$4,3]
}
```

Comment: nice comments! Good luck to all.

Comment: That works great! And thanks for the explanation. I should be able to modify it for similar problems.  Jim

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
NR==FNR{cr[$1]=$2;cm[$1]=$3;cs[$1]=$4;next}
{print $1,$2,cr[$2],$3,cm[$3],$4,cs[$4]}
' file2 file1
```

**Output**

```
Smith;3;5;7;5;4;15
Jones;8;18;2;2;9;50
Doe;1;1;9;7;4;15
```